# Database state set to an earlier state before creating new indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is a remote server (SQL Server 2008).

We are trying to get benchmarking of some stored procedures. One stored procedure was taking avrg 44 seconds, we have checked this approx 20 times for a span of two weeks avrg was 44 seconds.

SQL Profiler suggested a missing index, we created the suggested index for checking the performance. The execution time reduced significantly after indexing.

We dropped the newly created index. Rebuild index was not performed, as we assumed drop index should rebuild the index for the table.

Client is also testing on same db. They also felt a performance gain in this particular operation. They are asking the cause for this gain, we have conveyed the above process, but index benefit can also be verified  with older DB state, therefor we need to reset the data base to earlier state where it was taking 44 seconds.

Database Engine can not be restarted and Offline/Online options can also not be performed as "Alter Any Database" permission can not be granted.

We are looking on below command.

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO

Permissions
Requires ALTER SERVER STATE permission on the server.

USE <<db Name>>
GO
GRANT ALTER TO your_user
GO
```

Need help to understand the possible cause behind this behaviour?

Does `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` also clear the index cache?

Comment: Its still performing better because there are possibilities that statistics created with index still exists and optimizer is using these statistics to estimate cost and generating same optimum plan to execute. Remove all newly created statistics also and then clear cached plans and you will possibly get same old execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop the index, the database is in the same state as before in terms of indexing. If you want to go back to a previous state then you'll need to get a backup for that time range. Depending on the requirements it's either just the FULL Backup or additional DIFFERENTIAL Backups or even a point-in-time recovery using the transaction logs.

But the question is: Why do you want to do it in the first place?

The benefit of any index should not be explained by runnig it against an older data set just to see that it would have been better in the past, too, but by explaining the effect itself. Either a Scan has changed into a Seek operation and/or the new index is more narrow than the one previously used and/or a bookmark lookup has been eliminated and/or the index allows for a better performing query plan.

Also, verify that the statistics are up to date before comparing old and new version to eliminate the side effect of a better performance due to better statistics.

The index comparison should be done using the same procedure against the same set of data (e.g. current data) and compare the actual execution plans.

Comment: You have a point "Also, verify that the statistics are up to date before comparing old and new version to eliminate the side effect of a better performance due to better statistics.". I am also looking into the same direction now. Its quite possible that earlier 44 seconds was due to old stats.